# How do I send input to and get output from bc using Python?

Tags: python, command-line, bc

I can run bc with Python with the following code:

```
subprocess.Popen("bc", stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

However, this only launches bc, and I have to manually input whatever I want, for example, 1+1. I want to use Python to send 1+1 to bc and get the output. How would I do that?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? "Popen.communicate(input=None) - Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate. The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child."

Comment: Others have commented on how to use Popen.  I'll suggest that you consider using gmpy or gmpy2 instead of bc - these are C coded libraries for operating on potentially-huge numbers, callable from python.

Comment: What do I pass to "communicate"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. You have to have stdin as well as stdout, and call communicate with a string that ends in a newline, like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("bc", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate('1+1\n')
```

Where out is the output you want.

Comment: you could use `from subprocess import Popen, PIPE` to make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this:

```
dogface@computer ~
$ cat oneplusone
1+1
quit

dogface@computer ~
$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jul 23 2012, 16:48:24)
[GCC 4.5.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["bc", "-q", "oneplusone"])
2
0
```